# Read pixel in frame buffer object based on mouse click

Tags: opengl, 3d, glut

I'm using a frame buffer object to do offscreen rendering. This is how I'm initializing the FBO:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fb);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &color_rb);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, color_rb);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA8, windowWidth, windowHeight);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, color_rb);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depth_rb);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depth_rb);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, windowWidth, windowHeight);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depth_rb);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
```

In my glut mouse function, I'm trying to read the use the location clicked in the main window, to map to and read the corresponding pixel location in my FBO. However, I seem to be getting the pixel data from the main window instead of my offscreen rendered FBO. Here is my glut mouse func:

GLubyte pixel;

```
    glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
    glReadPixels(x, windowHeight - y - 1, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &pixel);

    cout << "Pixel clicked: " << (int) pixel << endl;
```

Does anyone know how can I use a click position in the main window, to read a corresponding pixel location in my FBO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glReadPixels` [reads from the framebuffer currently bound to `GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer#Buffer_reading). So if you want to read from it, you should bind it to that target before reading.

Alternatively, you can bind to `GL_FRAMEBUFFER`, which binds to both the `GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER` and `GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER`s.

Answer (score 2):

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
```

Try regular 'ole `GL_FRAMEBUFFER` instead of `GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER`.

Comment: I wish I could accept two answers because it was a combination of your answer and Nicol's answer that helped me figure this out. I decided to just flip a coin. Nicol won. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: No problem, so it goes.  Good luck!